# Laravel permission denied Centos 7

Tags: linux, laravel-4, permissions, centos7

I installed laravel 4.2 and i ended up with this error

> file_put_contents(/var/www/html/laravel4/app/storage/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied

I figured services.json dosent exist but when i do

```
php artisan up
```

The error changes to

> Error in exception handler: The stream or file "/var/www/html/laravel4/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/laravel4/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:87

I tried giving permessions to the storage and the vendor folders but nothing seems to be changing

```
php artisan cache:clear
chmod -R 777 app/storage
composer dump-autoload
```

I tried to give permession by doing this command

```
setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
```

I even deleted the project and created multiple copies from scratch nothing seems to be working help me i'm feeling so lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was using Vmware Vsphere to access the server
the access was restricted from there :( 
finally by giving access from there it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vmware Vsphere to access the server, you should give it the access to do this action.